# Range Selector date always goes to 1970-01-01 in Highcharts.Chart()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create bar line graph using `Highcharts.Chart()` and I want to add `rangeSelector` according to `inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'` format.

I saw there are lot of ways to add `rangeSelector` in `inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'` format using `Highcharts.stockChart()` but i couldn't able to find a way to do it using Highcharts.Chart(). I used milliseconds and normal date formats as input data set date format. But `rangeSelector` didn't work it always goes to 1970-01-01.

Is there any way to take `rangeSelector` as '%Y-%m-%d' format using Highcharts.Chart()?

this is millisecond format example - http://jsfiddle.net/0x35kL78/2/

this is month format example - http://jsfiddle.net/zuv1d4st/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons for why it defaults to 1970-01-01.

You are using strings for the x values. It needs to be numbers. So by changing all values from this:

```
['1551420000000', 49.9],
```

To

```
[1551420000000, 49.9],
```

That takes care of the first series, the second series (`[56.6,46.3,32.8,43.4,40.8,43.0,43.1,44.6,45.7,27.8,39.9,29.3,27.9,27.4,17.6]`) data does not have any timestamp, so it will by default be plotted like this:

```
[0, 56.6],
[1, 46.3],
[2, 32.8],
...
```

Which is 0,1,2 milliseconds after 1970-01-01. Your options are to either include the timestamp like for your first series. Or if the values are consistently spaced, you can use [pointStart](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointStart) and pointInterval to accomplish this.

I matched the second series values to your first series milliseconds for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vnkxrq80/4/

Comment: now 1m,3m,6m is not working. do you know to fix both?

Comment: Buttons are working correctly. Just your data has a different range than milliseconds that you've defined in buttons options.